# GRPC web client with angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, grpc, grpc-web

I have worked with grpc .net client and a grpc server created with java, how can i implement grpc web client on angular 6 with typescript? Also how can i create proto files and it's typing's for typescript?
I am following [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grpc-web-client) repo but not able to generate proto files.

Comment: Here is unofficial angular+grpc framework https://github.com/ngx-grpc/core

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After spending sometime i was able to create proto files for typescript by following steps:

1. Download protobuf for windows from this [link](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases). After extracting files set the path variable for protoc.exe
2. install npm packages `npm install google-protobuf @types/google-protobuf grpc-web-client ts-protoc-gen --save`
3. After installing it generate the typescript files by using the command:
   `protoc --plugin="protoc-gen-ts=absolute-path-to-your-project\node_modules\.bin\protoc-gen-ts.cmd" --js_out="import_style=commonjs,binary:${OUT_DIR}" --ts_out="service=true:${OUT_DIR}" your.proto`
4. Finally consume it like as mentioned in this [repo](https://github.com/improbable-eng/grpc-web/tree/master/ts#usage-overview).

Comment: Repo link not working, Can you please update that? thanks

Comment: @Synster I think this might do it. This is the official example for typescript on the grpc-web githug page: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/blob/master/net/grpc/gateway/examples/echo/ts-example/client.ts

Comment: I have a question, when I get response from grpc server, then how can I subscribe data?

Answer (score 5):

You can also get it to work by running:

```
npm install google-protobuf protoc ts-protoc-gen
```

Then add a compile script to your package.json:

```
"compile": "./node_modules/protoc/protoc/bin/protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-ts=./node_modules/.bin/protoc-gen-ts --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:src/app/proto-gen --ts_out=service=true:src/app/proto -I ./src/app/proto ./src/app/proto/**/*.proto",
```

now you can compile the .proto files to a Service using:

```
npm run compile
```

You can see the approach working here:

https://github.com/kmturley/angular-nest-grpc

Comment: Using grp-web from google - ` "compile": "./node_modules/protoc/protoc/bin/protoc  --plugin=protoc-gen-ts=./node_modules/.bin/protoc-gen-ts --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:src/app/proto  --grpc-web_out=import_style=typescript,mode=grpcweb:src/app/proto -I ./interfaces/ ./interfaces/**/*.proto",`

Answer (score 1):

grpc/grpc-web is available at https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web

Answer (score 1):

Cannot use on on Windows

```
"compile": "./node_modules/protoc/protoc/bin/protoc
--plugin=protoc-gen-ts=./node_modules/.bin/protoc-gen-ts --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:src/app/proto-gen --ts_out=service=true:src/app/proto -I ./src/app/proto ./src/app/proto/**/*.proto",
```

I get '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command

This works fine: package.json

```
"scripts": {
"compile": "node_modules\\protoc\\protoc\\bin\\protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-ts=node_modules\\.bin\\protoc-gen-ts.cmd --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:./proto/generated --ts_out=service=grpc-web:./proto/generated -I ./proto ./proto/*.proto"
}
```

npm run compile

Answer (score 0):

On windows Solution with automatic:

1. npm i @types/google-protobuf --save-dev
2. npm i google-protobuf --save
3. npm i grpc-web-client --save
4. npm i ts-protoc-gen --save

**Or for 1 to 4 can use this command:
npm i @types/google-protobuf  google-protobuf grpc-web-client ts-protoc-gen --save**

5. Add this line to package.json:

   "scripts": {

   ```
   "grpc:gen": "protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-ts=node_modules\\ts-protoc-gen\\bin\\protoc-gen-ts.cmd --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:proto\\out --ts_out=service=grpc-web:proto\\out proto\\greet.proto"
   ```

   }
6. generate ts file with this command `npm run grpc:gen`

code is available at here:
[Server for .net Core](https://gitlab.com/farshadbayat/grpc.net-core.git)
[Client for angular](https://gitlab.com/farshadbayat/angular-grpc.git)